# SHA-512 not supported by Java?

Tags: java, hash, sha

```
try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        byte[] output = digest.digest(password);

        digest.update(salt);
        digest.update(output);
        return new BigInteger(1, digest.digest());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(e);
    }
```

But I got `Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA_512 MessageDigest not available` error

Comment: http://mustafacanturk.com/sha512-hashing-on-java/

Comment: The exception message doesn't match your code: `SHA_512` vs the correct value in the code of `SHA-512`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say that the most likely explanation is that your REAL code has `"SHA_512"` rather than `"SHA-512"`.  Certainly, that would explain why there is an underscore in the exception message.

The other possibility is that you have a JVM with the "military strength" crypto algorithms removed because of US export restrictions.  However, I think that is pretty unlikely ...

(And in fact, my reading of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) is that SHA-512 was included in all versions of the default "Sun" provider anyway.)

Comment: Neither AES-256 is not included in JDK by default - read https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/395/enabling-aes256-in-the-java-runtime-environment-fo.html  .

Comment: @Xdg - That is not apropos to this answer, or to the question.  For a start, AES-256 is an *encryption* algorithm, not a hashing algorithm.  And that article is out of date.  Per https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8170157,  AES-256 is no longer restricted access in Java 7 and later.  (Check the bug report for the specific build versions where the restrictions were lifted.)

Answer (score 17):

The following are the [standard hashing algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest) provided by the Java `MessageDigest`:

- MD2
- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-256
- SHA-384
- SHA-512

You may want to verify the name you are supplying to the factory method.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. By default Java does not ship with a SHA3 MessageDigest provider. But it looks like [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html) has included it in their library.

Comment: Please note that the SHA-384 implemention works by truncating the results from SHA-512, Hence it will require the same amount of calculation as SHA-512

Comment: What you list are the standard `MessageDigest` _names_. But the document you referenced makes no guarantee that any of these will actually be _supported_ by any particular JDK implementation. In fact as of Java 17, the [`MessageDigest` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/MessageDigest.html) still indicates that the JDK is only guaranteed to support `SHA-1` and `SHA-256`. If you have some updated specification that makes further guarantees, please share it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the sample method which can be used to get hash string through SHA-512:

```
private static String getHashCodeFromString(String algorithm, String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    md.update(str.getBytes());
    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

    //convert the byte to hex format method 1
    StringBuffer hashCodeBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
        hashCodeBuffer.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }
    return hashCodeBuffer.toString();
}
```

use `SHA-512` as algorithm. go to following link for other possible algorithm name you can pass in method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Answer (score 2):

> The MessageDigest class is an engine class designed to provide the
>   functionality of cryptographically secure message digests such as
>   SHA-1 or MD5. A cryptographically secure message digest takes
>   arbitrary-sized input (a byte array), and generates a fixed-size
>   output.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#MessageDigest)

To print all the `MessageDigest`  provider -

```
Provider provider[] = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider pro : provider) {
    System.out.println(pro);
    for (Enumeration e = pro.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
        System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());

}
```

And fortunatly `SHA-512` is there but `SHA_512` is not. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy language you can use below method to generate hash string through SHA-512.

It's completely working for me.

```
public String getHashCodeFromString(String algorithm, String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
      md.update(str.getBytes());
      def byteData = md.digest() as byte[];

      //convert the byte to hex format method 1
      StringBuffer hashCodeBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
        hashCodeBuffer.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
      }
      return hashCodeBuffer.toString();
    }
```